# Formatting matplotlib x limits

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
x = np.linspace(2000.0, 2018.0, num = 18)

for i in range(len(x)):
    x[i]=int(x[i])


for i in range(2000, 2018):
    y.append(dic[str(i)])


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(x, y, marker='o', color='r')

# set title

# set label for x

# set label for y

print(ax.get_xlim())

return ax
```

I am trying to plot a 18 points where x limit should be from (2000.0) to (2018.0). Some codes are hidden, but I just posted the critical parts. When I print the result out, the xlimit is

```
(1999.0999999999999, 2018.9000000000001)
```

not

```
(2000.0, 2018.0)
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: To make this reproducible, what is `y`?

Comment: y is a specific value that the x has in a dictionary. So, this is just like plotting (x,y) points. And I have to use plot(), not scatterplot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong; but you may have the wrong expectation concerning the limits of the plot.

By default, matplotlib leaves 5% margin on each side of the plot. Hence, if your data is in the range `[x.min(), x.max()] == [2000.0, 2018.0]` your limits will be

```
[x.min()-0.05*(x.max()-x.min()), x.max()+0.05*(x.max()-x.min())] == [1999.1, 2018.9]
```

If you don't want to have any padding around your data, use `ax.margins(x=0)`. In that case `print(ax.get_xlim())` will print `(2000.0, 2018.0)`

Complete example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(2000.0, 2018.0, num = 19)
y = np.cumsum(np.random.rand(len(x)))

x = x.astype(int)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(x, y, marker='o', color='r')
ax.margins(x=0)

print(ax.get_xlim())
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to set the xlim yourself. `matplotlib` automatically select the limits and ticks.

so you need to use

```
ax.set_xlim([x[0],x[-1]])
```

For the xlim to be exactly what you want.

see plot below[image]

Comment: The first and end value gets it correct, but the values in between are still weird. They have bunch of decimals like -  2001.0588235294117,
-  2002.1176470588234.

Comment: Yes, but I think this answer solves the asked question.

Comment: you will have to specify the xticks using `ax.set_xticks(x)`. I suggest making your question more clear

Comment: You mean for each x value?

Comment: if that what you want, if you want to display the values in x use the line in my previous comment is the way to go. using set_xticks, you can also use a subset of x, e.g. passing `x[::2]` to `set_xticks` will show every other item in x on the x-axis

Comment: so if we want to set other values to 2001, 2002, etc. How does that work?

Comment: simply pass a list of the values you want. I suggest referring to the [matplotlib documentation on xticks](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html?highlight=matplotlib%20pyplot%20xticks#matplotlib.pyplot.xticks), they provide many examples